# How to mock methods using mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I have an abstract class and a derived class. The derived class is a serivce so is autowired into the test class. Theres a method in the abstract class that I need to mock and test. My current implementation is not working and I'm not sure why.

I've created a spy of the class I want to test and I've called the method using the spy in the test. But still mockito fails to return my mocked value.

```
abstract class AbstractMyClass {
    fun hello(): String {
        "bello"
    }
}

@Service
class MyClass: AbstractMyClass() {}
```

My Test stub is

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var myClass: MyClass


@Test
fun `test hello`() {
  val spy = Mockito.spy(myClass)
  Mockito.doReturn("cello").`when`(spy).hello()
  val res = spy.hello()
  Assert.assertEquals("cello", res)
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, the methods are final by default. Thus, `AbstractMyClass::hello()` is final and since you never override it in `MyClass` it remains so and Mockito will not stub it.

To get the above code to work you need to open the method in `AbstractMyClass`:

```
abstract class AbstractMyClass {
    open fun hello(): String {
        "bello"
    }
}
```

BTW, it is unclear from your example what exactly you are trying to test. I don't suppose you are testing the behaviour of `MyClass` here...

Comment: This is a representation of my actual problem. In my actual code, I need to test a method in `AbstractMyClass` that calls `hello`. So, basically I need to mock the method `hello` to return a certain value. 
I tried using `open` in the method but it still doesn't work. Mockito still calls the method.

Something very weird happens actually. I put a break pointer on line `val res = spy.hello()` in the test and in `hello` method in my abstract class. 
Ideally the pointer should stop at the line `val res = spy.hello()`, but instead it stops inside the `hello` method.

Comment: Basically ` Mockito.doReturn("cello").`when`(spy).hello()` in my test is calling the `hello()` method and not mocking it.. Why is this so?